# Only write to file if data doesn't exist?

Tags: node.js, json, fs

I am creating a push notification server, and I am storing subscriptions in a JSON file, called `clients.json`. This is working just fine, and I am able to use `fs.writeFile('clients.json', data, callback)`, which is working. The problem I am having is that if there are multiple instances of a subscription in the JSON file, the server sends a push event multiple times, for every instance of the subscription.
What I am trying now is to only write the subscription object to the file if it does not already exist in the file. I have tried the following:

```
if (!JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('clients.json')).endpoints.includes(subscription)) {
    clients.endpoints.push(subscription);
    fs.writeFile('clients.json', JSON.stringify(clients), err=>{if(err){console.log(err)}});
}
```

Seems correct to me, but it doesn't seem to care about my condition, as the code block runs every time and the subscription is inserted to the file many times.
If it helps, this is `clients.json`:

```
{
    "endpoints":[
        /* Client subscriptions end up in this array */
    ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot more appropriate data structures for a problem like this than a flat file of JSON.  For example, many simple databases would be very good at this.  Also, storing the data in memory as a Map with the client ID as the key would make this trivial to update.  If you don't already have the client subscription in the Map, then you can add it and then update the disk format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In js only primitive types are compared by their values. If `subscription` is an object of any kind, it will return `false` when compared with another object, even when it contains the same data, because they are compared by object they reference.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Each `subscription` is a JSON object, which I am storing in a JSON file. I could run `JSON.stringify(clients).indexOf(JSON.stringify(subscription))` to check if the subscription exists in the file already. Very helpful :)